# Invalid audio strips with negative length

Tags: audio

When I add audio strips, they are inverted and they don't play. They also are unable to move with the mouse or with the <kbd>G</kbd> button. This audio plays successfully if I open them not in Blender.
How can I solve this problem to add audio strips that will work?
[image: audio strip]
[image: edit panel]

Comment: It might be an issue with the compression (codec) used on the file. Convert the file to a .wav format and see what happens.

Comment: I work with mp3 files, they always have opened in a proper way.

Comment: I have just found one of my blender files in which audio add like it always was and now I work in this file, so this problem isn't critical for me. However, if I create a new blender project, there will be this problem.